Не работает поиск с русским языком SQL
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = CONVERT('$query' USING utf8) OR SUBSTRING(name, 1, LENGTH(name) - 2) = CONVERT('$query' USING utf8) OR SUBSTRING(name, 1, LENGTH(name) - 1) = CONVERT('$query' USING utf8)

Запрос должен искать имена пользователей с точностью до -2 символов, т.е. если ввожу 'Alex', то находит строку 'Alexey' , проблема такая , с русским именем работает только если ввел полное имя

Какую СУБД используете?

В MySQL функция LENGTH возвращает количество байт, а не букв. А русские буквы занимают по 2 байта

Попробуйте конструкцию
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '$query__' or name LIKE '$query_'

